# Loop SQL by month

Tags: sql, oracle, loops, date, calendar

In Oracle SQL Developer I need to calculate some figures (count for instance) since first day till today monthly. How can I create a loop by changing month in a date field? Now I have a time range on WHERE clause like (date >= '2017-01-01' and date < '2019-01-01'). So what I need is a table that counts for months and inserts results in two columns: month (2019_01, 2019_02, etc) and count

Comment: SQL doesn't really have loops, so it's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: A general pattern is to expand the date range into a list of individual months (e.g. with a hierarchical query) as a CTE or inline view, and then (outer) join from that to your real data. The options for how to do that will depend on your Oracle version though.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example which might help you do what need. It is based on Scott's sample schema, its `EMP` table that contains the `HIREDATE` column which will be joined to a CTE named `months`; it utilizes hierarchical query to create "calendar" of 12 months (that's what the `CONNECT BY` clause does). It will have to be changed in your case, I presume.

Current data:

```
SQL> select empno, ename, hiredate
  2  from emp
  3  order by hiredate;

     EMPNO ENAME      HIREDATE
---------- ---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH      17.12.1980
      7499 ALLEN      20.02.1981
      7521 WARD       22.02.1981
      7566 JONES      02.04.1981
      7698 BLAKE      01.05.1981
      7782 CLARK      09.06.1981
      7844 TURNER     08.09.1981
      7654 MARTIN     28.09.1981
      7839 KING       17.11.1981
      7900 JAMES      03.12.1981
      7902 FORD       03.12.1981
      7934 MILLER     23.01.1982
      7788 SCOTT      09.12.1982
      7876 ADAMS      12.01.1983

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Query you might need:

```
SQL> with months as
  2    (select add_months(date '1980-12-01', level - 1) mon
  3     from dual
  4     connect by level <= 12
  5    )
  6  select to_char(m.mon, 'mm.yyyy') mon,
  7         count(e.empno)
  8  from months m left join emp e on m.mon = trunc(e.hiredate, 'mm')
  9  group by m.mon
 10  order by m.mon;

MON     COUNT(E.EMPNO)
------- --------------
12.1980              1   --> Smith
01.1981              0
02.1981              2   --> Allen, Ward
03.1981              0
04.1981              1   --> Jones
05.1981              1   --> Blake
06.1981              1   --> Clark
07.1981              0
08.1981              0
09.1981              2   --> Turner, Martin
10.1981              0
11.1981              1   --> King

12 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: I suppose it should. Give it a try.